# How do you measure performance of spring boot api with limited resources?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin

Let's say we have a monolithic rest API written in Java with Spring Boot. And we want to do some performance analysis on it, how would we go about it?

The problem is measuring its performance with custom maximum usage requirements, for example, maximum ram, CPU cores, CPU clock speed, etc.

Knowing this can be useful, such as predicting cloud and other hosting fees, what is the best way of doing it?

Comment: Micrometer, Grafana, Prometheus, Datadog, New Relic, etc...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe you can use Spring metrics and tracing? https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/metrics-and-tracing/

Also might wanna look at Grafana k6

https://circleci.com/blog/api-performance-testing-with-k6/

and Micrometer

https://micrometer.io/

Using Docker and VM should help you limiting your hardware.

Comment: Good answer, however my main issue is how do i limit ram, cpu, cores, etc. I cannot find the answer anywhere

Comment: @FikiCar I see you're trying to limit ram, cpu, etc...Docker could help with that

Comment: @FikiCar as said above, Docker or a VM should help limiting RAM, CPU and other stuff. I don't think you can do that from a tracking app though(not sure about it).

Comment: @Vlad1791 yes, i guess its not possible. I was hoping i could automate testing process but it seems like I will have to do it all almost manually. Add to you answer that using docker and vm should help with limiting, so that i can accept it.

Comment: Got it. I modified the answer